# Set null as default to date or datetime in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Hello I am new to sql server. Here I need to set the variable of type date or datetime as null by default in SQL Server.

**Example**:

```
create proc test 
@fdate date default null
@tdate date default null
@ftime datetime default null
@tdate datetime default null
as 
  ...
  ...
go
```

**Error**:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DEFAULT'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create proc test 
@fdate date = null,
@tdate date = null,
@ftime datetime = null,
@tdate datetime = null
as 
  ...
  ...
```